# Атрибуты модуля scapy

Tags: python, arp, scapy

Не могу найти расшифровку нескольких атрибутов в scapy. psrc, pdst, hwdst, hwsrc, op - [пример кода]`send(ARP(op=2, psrc=gateway_ip, pdst=target_ip, hwdst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", hwsrc=gateway_mac), count=5)`. Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- psrc - ip источника
- pdst - ip назначения
- hwsrc - mac-адрес источника
- hwdst - mac-адрес назначения (ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff - широковещательный)

Судя по передаваемым параметрам - предпринимается попытка притвориться маршрутизатором?

Comment: op - тип arp-пакета. В представленном примере 2 = 'is-at'

Comment: Можешь рассказать по больше о op? Что такое who has и is at?

Comment: op это ARP operation. Их всего две, запрос ('who has' that ip) и ответ (that ip 'is at' that mac). Более подробно в википедии есть https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP